# Angular Using promise & then in the for loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback, angular-promise

I would like to ask that is possible (and how) to use promise with "callback" in Angular for the for loop?

It means something like:

```
 $scope.changeToBigImages = function() {
      for(var productsLinkAli in $scope.productImagesThumbs.aliexpress) {
        $scope.convertToBigSrc($scope.productImagesThumbs.aliexpress[productsLinkAli], URL_TYPE_ALIEXPRESS);
      }
      for(var productsLinkEbay in $scope.productImagesThumbs.ebay) {
        $scope.convertToBigSrc($scope.productImagesThumbs.ebay[productsLinkEbay], URL_TYPE_EBAY);
      }
      //If 1.st a 2.nd for loop is finished, next action should be triggered
    }


$scope.convertToBigSrc = function(LINK_THUMB, TYPE) {
      var bigImage;
      console.log(LINK_THUMB);
      console.log(TYPE);
      switch (TYPE) {
        case URL_TYPE_EBAY:
          var replacedImgs = [];
          for(var productsLinkEbay in LINK_THUMB) {
            bigImage = LINK_THUMB[productsLinkEbay].replace(IMG_PATH_EBAY_FIND, IMG_PATH_EBAY_REPLACE); //http://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/uSYAAOSw7FRWZIvs/s-l64.jpg
            replacedImgs.push(bigImage);
          }
          $scope.productImagesBig.ebay.push(replacedImgs);
          break;
        case URL_TYPE_ALIEXPRESS:
          var replacedImgs = [];
          for(var productsLinkAli in LINK_THUMB) {
            bigImage = LINK_THUMB[productsLinkAli].replace(IMG_PATH_ALI_FIND, IMG_PATH_ALI_REPLACE); //http://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/uSYAAOSw7FRWZIvs/s-l64.jpg
            replacedImgs.push(bigImage);
          }
          $scope.productImagesBig.aliexpress.push(replacedImgs);
          break;
      }
    }
```

I know that i can watch value of the index in the for loop, but i would like to know that is possible (and optimal) to use something like promises.

Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: Is $scope.convertToBigSrc returns a promise? if yes, then you can store all promises in an variable then you can use $q.all(promises).then(function(){ //do other stuffs here }); to do the things after the completion of promises.

Comment: Could You please add some example please? convertToBigSrc is not returning promise (I updated my question).

Comment: All your code is sync - no point to use promises. But of course you can.